# Testing the .NET Micro Framework timer

Tags: c#, timer, .net-micro-framework

I want to get an idea of how much jitter there is in the .NET Micro Framework timer. Online, I haven't seen anywhere that this has been profiled.

To do the profiling myself I need to know how the MF scheduler works wrt the timer interrupt, and all I've seen is broad overviews. I know that when a timer interrupt occurs it has to wait for any current thread to complete the quantum or to block. What are the other factors?

Suppose, for instance, I set up a thread that consumes the entire quantum every time it's activated. Will it be worse if I add another thread that does the same thing? Suppose I have another timer whose callback runs a long time? What about two such timers?

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: It is an unanswerable question, MF has many possible targets.  What you get greatly depends on what the processor can do.

Comment: I'm not trying to get absolute numbers that are true across all platforms; I want to understand how scheduling the timer callback affects timer jitter. A profiling program based on that could be run on any platform to get the upper and lower bounds for the platform.